# Unable to install application on BlackBerry due to Error 907

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am presently developing a PhoneGap application ( targeting BlackBerry OS 6/7 ).The application runs fine on the Ripple Emulator, and builds OK on the PhoneGap Build Service.

When I try to install over-the-air from PhoneGap build on a physical test device ( a BlackBerry Curve 9300 ), I constantly get variations of the "907 error" - invalid Jar / Invalid cod etc. I have also tried to install from my own server, with a JAD that I created and verified, and with MIME types correctly set - with the same result.

When I attempt the installation via BlackBerry Desktop software, I get "silent failures" ie BB Desktop simply loops back to the application list, without installing the software.

I have searched through the BlackBerry forums and knowledge bases, and tried to apply the recommendations contained there. For example:

[BlackBerry Forum Entry on the 907 Error](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/907-Invalid-Jar-Error-when-installing-an-application-wirelessly/ta-p/445056)

[Knowledge Base Article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800708/800646/Support_-_907_Invalid_Jar_Error_when_installing_an_application_wirelessly.html?nodeid=1017517&vernum=0)

The physical test device has BlackBerry service ( push email, BlackBerry App World etc are working ). This problem has so far defined my attempts to resolve it ( although I am not giving up yet ). Any pointers in what I should consider?

Comment: How big is your app? If it's bigger than 70kb than most probably the cod file is just zip that keeps smaller cod files. for OTA installation you have to unzip all them to the same folder where is jad. I would also try "Javaloader.exe -u load *.cod" to check that your app is loadable to device at all.

Comment: I eventually found that the app had >127 COD files in it, so it wouldn't install. The only way to whittle it down to an installable size - that I have found - is to rip out embedded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this 907.

My compiled application had more than 127 sibling CODs. On "traditional" BlackBerry ( up to Blackberry 7; I am not sure this behavior extends to BB10 and PlayBook ), an application cannot have more than 127 sibling CODs.

There are also absolute size limits, related to the fact that each COD has a size limit of 128kB ( 64kB Data / 64kB code ). The practical absolute size limit is therefore dependent on what fraction of your app is code and what fraction is data ( there is a strict separation ).

My current headache is on how to embed my content in the app, in spite of this limit. I have posted that as an independent question:

[I need to embed a > 4MB Content File in a BlackBerry Webworks Application ( fror BlackBerry 6/7 ). What are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078052/i-need-to-embed-a-4mb-content-file-in-a-blackberry-webworks-application-fror)

Comment: An entry by Tim Neil in the BB support forums ( http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/RAPC-exception-occurred/td-p/1188705 ) mentions 7MB as the limit.