# I need to embed a > 4MB Content File in a BlackBerry Webworks Application ( fror BlackBerry 6/7 ). What are my options?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am in the process of developing a content-heavy Webworks app. In order for the app to be useful, it needs to maintain a local content database ( approx. 4MB in SQL form; the only way to reduce it further is to rip out entire categories of content ).

My original thinking was that I would embed the SQL file in the app ( just like the CSS and JS ), then load into SQlite on first run. The strategy worked in development on the Ripple emulator.

When I attempted to build and run on a real test device, grief resulted. The compiled COD had > 127 sibling CODs, so it wouldn't install ( took a week to find that out ).

I have prototyped a different approach - downloading the SQL file from the web on first run. I do not like this second approach - with reason; this application is intended for use in a zone of the world that has expensive / spotty bandwidth.

Is there a way to embed significant amounts of content in a BlackBerry application for BB 6/7 without running into application size limits ( either number of Sibling CODs [ cannot exceed 127 ] or absolute size of the application)?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/1300209

Specifically this:

> The limit for the number of sibling COD files that can exist within a
> single application is 127.  This means that the maximum theoretical
> size limit for an application would be 16256 KB, which consists of
> 8128 KB of application data and 8128 KB of resource data. There is
> some overhead to this value, which brings the actual maximum size
> limit closer to 14000 KB.  The actual maximum size for an application
> will vary slightly based on the application's contents.
>
> It is not possible for either data type (application or resource) to
> make use of unused space of another data type, meaning resource data
> cannot use application data space even if the application data is well
> under the limit.

Comment: An official answer in the BB support forums ( http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/RAPC-exception-occurred/td-p/1188705 , see last comment) mentions 7MB as the limit. For my app - when I drop in the SQL file, I get > 127 CODs. When I remove it, the number of CODs reduce. Even with the SQL file in, the application size is still below 7MB. I had encountered that knowledge base article ( and documented that in a previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896736/unable-to-install-application-on-blackberry-due-to-error-907 ).